# the biggest number with the most divisor for a new python learner

Tags: python, greatest-common-divisor

I don't know how to write a program that is able to get 20 numbers in the `input()` and returns the biggest number, even if two or more numbers have the same amount of divisor, I want the biggest one for the answer.

```
def divisor():
n = 0
answer = 0
temp_1 =0
temp_2 = 0
while True:
    temp_1=0
    n = int(input('Enter your number: '))
    if n <=0:
        break
    for i in range(1, n+1):          
        if n % i == 0:
            temp_1+=1
    if temp_1>=temp_2:
        if(n > answer):
            answer = n
            temp_2 = temp_1
            my_list = []
            my_list.append(n)
    for i in range(n):
        x = len([i for i in range(1,n+1) if not n % i])
return f'{answer} {x}'
print(divisor())
```

this is my code but it doesn't work the way I want and I think it's not really readable, I myself got confused using it.
Could you please help me in this in a way that a new python learner could understand it? Thx a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you share your code so far, please? Also, you need to be a bit more specific, where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: I edited my post dear, Roland, I hope that would do the clarification

Comment: Hi, I'm guessing this is for some sort of assignment? Are you allowed to use some package such as numpy for example? Or do you have to make the gcd calculation manually?

Comment: yes, it"s an assignment, not for someone else, but for myself, there is no condition for doing it but as far as I am a new python learner, I'm not sure if I understand NumPy

Comment: Ah ok, cool. Give me a sec :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you need:

```
import numpy as np
 
def inputNumber(message):
  while True:
    try:
       userInput = int(input(message))       
    except ValueError:
       print("Not an integer! Try again.")
       continue
    else:
       return userInput 
       break 
   
def divisor(number_of_inputs):
    all_numbers = np.zeros(number_of_inputs, dtype='int')
    
    for i in range(number_of_inputs):
        all_numbers[i] = inputNumber("Enter your Number: ")
    
    return np.gcd.reduce(all_numbers)
    
print(divisor(20))
```

If you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: Thx a lot dear, Roland. can we do that without the NumPy module in an easier way?

Comment: Sure, but you will have to implement the `gcd` functionality yourself. Instead of the numpy array, maybe just make a normal array or a python list.

Comment: wow, there is a method for this case, thx a lot, how would the code be like using this GCD method?

Comment: I'm not sure, what you mean? But if my answer helps you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I want a code without using any library, I am new to python, I want it understandable to my knowledge dear Roland.

Comment: Implementing a gcd functionality shouldn't be too hard and there are many examples out there. For example, [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gcd-in-python/) was the first entry after a short google search.